# How to change Camel quartz time during runtime

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I have tried looking all over the internet and didn't find any proper document regarding camel quartz to change its time during run time. Does any one know how to work on it with out starting and stopping the camel route.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable JMX on quartz, then you can use JMX to change the timer. But beware doing so for cron is hard from jconsole as the quartz JMX API is not very good. The camel-quartz should enable JMX out of the box if you are using a fairly new version of Camel.

The hawtio web console has a quartz plugin that has a facade JMX API [1] that makes it easier to change the cron expression, which we also made the web console have a nice UI that allows you to do so.

- http://hawt.io/
- [1] https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/hawtio-system/src/main/java/io/hawt/jmx/QuartzFacade.java

Comment: While using JMX will technically modify the value, it's not really a programmatic solution provided by the API. While I think camel is a helpful framework, I do view this as a shortcoming to the quartz and timer endpoints. It would be far more useful to have a programmatic way to change the schedule values versus being told "go use JMX". Perhaps the answer is creating a "master route" that constantly checks for change and if it does change, destroys the current route and recreates a new one with the new values? Maybe this could be handled internally by the API so users don't have to hack it?